# Ionic framework PdfViewer

Tags: pdf, ionic-framework

I want to develop pdf ebook application for mobile. Is there pdf viewer component for ionic framework. I fond mozilla pdf.js . I need ionic project example.

Comment: what version of Ionic are you working with?

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried the angular module [ng-pdfviewer](https://github.com/akrennmair/ng-pdfviewer)? Because angular works under the hood of Ionic.

Answer (score 3):

```
 var app = angular.module('testApp', [ 'ngPDFViewer' ]);

 app.controller('TestCtrl', [ '$scope', 'PDFViewerService', function($scope, pdf) {
  $scope.viewer = pdf.Instance("viewer");

  $scope.nextPage = function() {
    $scope.viewer.nextPage();
  };

  $scope.prevPage = function() {
    $scope.viewer.prevPage();
  };

  $scope.pageLoaded = function(curPage, totalPages) {
    $scope.currentPage = curPage;
    $scope.totalPages = totalPages;
  };
  }]);
```

And the Directive  uses the above pdf.js file 
and the Html is bellow:

```
<button ng-click="prevPage()">&lt;</button>
<button ng-click="nextPage()">&gt;</button>
<br>
<span>{{currentPage}}/{{totalPages}}</span>
<br>
<pdfviewer src="test.pdf" on-page-load='pageLoaded(page,total)' id="viewer"></pdfviewer>
```

and using ng-pdf should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this Phonegap plugin https://github.com/ti8m/DocumentHandler

Below is how I used it.

```
 $scope.HandleDocumentPlugin = function () {
    if (DocumentViewer != null) {
        DocumentViewer.previewFileFromUrlOrPath(
            function () {
                console.log('success');
            }, function (error) {
                if (error == 53) {
                    console.log('No app that handles this file type.');
                    var alert = $ionicPopup.alert({
                        title: 'Alert!',
                        template: "There is no app installed that handles this file type."
                    });
                    alert.then(function (res) {

                    });
                }
            }, $scope.PDF_URL);
    }
    else if (DocumentHandler != null) {
        DocumentHandler.previewFileFromUrlOrPath(
           function () {
               console.log('success');
           }, function (error) {
               if (error == 53) {
                   console.log('No app that handles this file type.');
                   var alert = $ionicPopup.alert({
                       title: 'Alert!',
                       template: "There is no app installed that handles this file type."
                   });
                   alert.then(function (res) {

                   });
               }
           }, $scope.PDF_URL);
    }
    else {
        console.log("error");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use Cordova - InAppBrowser since it will be able to display pdf just open specify the static or dynamic path . you do need to add other modules as this an be also used to open web pages also you could use

https://github.com/initialxy/cordova-plugin-themeablebrowser

to theme the pdf openings for  custom loading to hide url etc fields

these two approaches can be used to open a simple pdf  document for reading purposes.

but for more specific options you should go with

https://github.com/akrennmair/ng-pdfviewer

which requires pdf.js and pdf.compat.js.

add it as a dependency in your app.

```
var app = angular.module('testApp', [ 'ngPDFViewer' ]);
```

basic controller syntax useage :

```
app.controller('TestCtrl', [ '$scope', 'PDFViewerService', function($scope, 
pdf) {
    $scope.viewer = pdf.Instance("viewer");

    $scope.nextPage = function() {
        $scope.viewer.nextPage();
    };

    $scope.prevPage = function() {
        $scope.viewer.prevPage();
    };

    $scope.pageLoaded = function(curPage, totalPages) {
        $scope.currentPage = curPage;
        $scope.totalPages = totalPages;
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [pdfmake](http://pdfmake.org/) library to generate the pdf, there is a good [example](https://github.com/jeffleus/ionic-pdf)  to integrate it to ionic