# ionic how to open pdf file and see in device for both ios and android

Tags: html, angularjs, pdf, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I have one pdf url. When i try to open its working in browser. But when i try to open in both android and ios device. My pdf file is not opening to see. Here my code :

**My Controller :**

```
$window.OpenLink = function(link) {
    window.open( link, '_system');
  };
```

**My html code on-click:**

```
<div  class="col col-50 clsGrid" onclick="OpenLink('http://www.orimi.com/pdf-test.pdf')">
```

Please help me out. How can i open my pdf file and see in both android and ios device.

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: You will have to use third party plugins

Answer (score 3, accepted):

install plugin

```
cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser.git
```

then try this

```
<a class="item" href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.orimi.com/pdf-test.pdf', '_system', 'location=yes'); return false;">
  Open pdf
                </a>
```

Comment: this code `<a class="item" href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.orimi.com/pdf-test.pdf', '_system', 'location=yes'); return false;">
  Open pdf
                </a>` fully i need to do or else i can do like this  <div  class="col col-50 clsGrid "href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.orimi.com/pdf-test.pdf', '_system', 'location=yes'); return false;">
                        <div class="clsGridOverlay"><span class="clsGridTitle">PDF</span></div>
                    </div>

Comment: can you please help me for this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43496455/how-to-show-pdf-file-in-ionic-app-with-out-download

Comment: @V.Pivet replace file root with local path

Comment: Great for ionic 4

Comment: Something that I have found very useful about this approach, is that while plugins like FileOpener use the device's native reader by default, those readers also have sharing options enabled. InAppBrowser allows me to disable them.

Answer (score 0):

Similar question asked here. [Ionic framework PdfViewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28981387/ionic-framework-pdfviewer/44182341#44182341)

Try using this Phonegap plugin https://github.com/ti8m/DocumentHandler
It worked perfectly for me.

Below is how I integrated it.

```
$scope.HandleDocumentPlugin = function () {
    if (DocumentViewer != null) {
        DocumentViewer.previewFileFromUrlOrPath(
            function () {
                console.log('success');
            }, function (error) {
                if (error == 53) {
                    console.log('No app that handles this file type.');
                    var alert = $ionicPopup.alert({
                        title: 'Alert!',
                        template: "There is no app installed that handles this file type."
                    });
                    alert.then(function (res) {

                    });
                }
            }, $scope.PDF_URL);
    }
    else if (DocumentHandler != null) {
        DocumentHandler.previewFileFromUrlOrPath(
           function () {
               console.log('success');
           }, function (error) {
               if (error == 53) {
                   console.log('No app that handles this file type.');
                   var alert = $ionicPopup.alert({
                       title: 'Alert!',
                       template: "There is no app installed that handles this file type."
                   });
                   alert.then(function (res) {

                   });
               }
           }, $scope.PDF_URL);
    }
    else {
        console.log("error");
    }
}
```

Comment: what i need is, i need to show the pdf,in both ios & android... to user WITH OUT DOWNLOAD... Your solution will work to show the pdf without download ?

Comment: Yes it will. I did the same thing.

Comment: Okay, this above solution is not clear me..because i have one grid view , once i press that grid view i need to show the pdf to suer without download...so its should be a on-clikc function right ??.. but the above solution i dont know how can i  do inside on-click function......if u have any source code..that will be more help full for me...becasue for this issue - i got more problem in my company...no help for me....if u send me some code that u used ...it will be usefull to save my job..

Comment: but i saw in plugin in github...they said....it will download the document in phone and then it will show preview to user

Comment: Are you using ionic framework or simple jquery javascript?

Comment: @DevSab..but i need ...the pdf should not be downlaod for user and should not save in phone storage also ...so this thing i can do with this plugin ?

Comment: i am using ionic 1

Comment: Give me an hour I'll get back to you with proper steps to follow

Comment: @hybridDev Hmm.. you were right it downloads the pdf and then open it. Sorry about that it was a long time ago when I used this plugin so was not sure if downloads or not. I think if it's really important not to download the pdf then you would have to switch to inappbrowswer plugin and show the pdf in phones browser. I'll try creating a sample app today with inappbrowser, will share if it works.

Comment: Try going through this discussion as well https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-open-external-pdf-url-in-app/14143/4